# CaptureElement class for WPF

Tags: wpf, windows-8

I read the class article [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/windows.media.capture.mediacapture) Class and on the bottom it says that the Minimum supported client - Windows 8 [Windows Store apps, desktop apps].

So I just used the Example writen there and used it for a WPF application. But then I saw that the object [CaptureElement](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4e9b42eb-7e75-4df3-838d-634fdc004955/captureelement-class-for-wpf?forum=windowscompatibility) is Minimum supported client - Windows 8 [Windows Store apps only].

So MediaCapture using CaptureElement is not for desktop apps. Is there a workaround for this?!

Thanks